# Numerous errors in R

Tags: r, regression

I have numerous errors popping up throughout. I'm still getting values, but I'm not sure how accurate they are. In fixing these errors, I tried starting from the top and playing with the variable definitions I had, but came up empty.

```
contdepdata <- read.delim("/Users/Jkels/Documents/Introduction to 
Computational Statistics/winequality-
red.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
contdepdata <- na.omit(contdepdata)
numericvars <- c(1:11)
dim(contdepdata)
head(contdepdata)

insample <- contdepdata[1:500,]
outsample <- contdepdata[501:1000,]
insamplex <- insample[x,]
outsamplex <- outsample[x,]
insampley <- insample[y,]
outsampley <- outsample[y,]

x <- insample[,numericvars]
y <- insample$quality

lambdalevels <- 10^seq(7,-2,length=100)

lmout <- lm(insampley~insamplex, data=insample)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = insampley ~ insamplex, data = insample,  : invalid type (list) for variable 'insampley'

```
yhatr <- cbind(1,outsamplex) %*% lmout$coefficients
```

> Error in cbind(1, outsamplex) %*% lmout$coefficients : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Comment: you should ask one question per error. the idea of this site is not just for you to get your problems solved, but also for the answers to be useful to others. make sure you also search here and in a search engine for the errors first, and check out the R documentation for the functions you used. splitting up into separate questions also makes it more likely for you to get answers.

Comment: This is a messy question. What do you get with  `attributes(contdepdata)`? Looking online, this data set seems to have columns named `fixed.acidity, volatile.acidity, citric.acid, residual.sugar, chlorides, free.sulfur.dioxide, total.sulfur.dioxide, density, pH, sulphates, alcohol` and `quality`. Where did `x` and `y` come from? Really you should consider linking your question to the dataset if you are serious about getting help from the SO community.

Comment: You shouldn't trust a result until you have investigated each and every warning, let alone if there are errors. The first error occurs because `insampley` is a data.frame (though how that happens when you define `x` and `y` only later I don't know). Assuming there is an `x` column in your data I *think* you were intending `insamplex <- insample[, "x"]` (and so forth).

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this is close to what you want. There's a huge difference between the formula/dataframes strategy used by lm and the matrix strategy used by glmnet, which I think is part of what's tripping you up. Frankly, I find glmnet's use of matrices disappointing (thought maybe it's necessary, I've never used it before).

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(glmnet)

data = 
  data_frame(a = rnorm(10),
             b = rnorm(10),
             c = "delete",
             quality = rnorm(10)) %>%
  extract(c(1:2, which(names(.) == "quality")))

data.training = 
  data %>%
  slice(1:5)

data.test = 
  data %>%
  slice(6:10)

quality.predict = 
  ( quality ~ . ) %>%
  lm(data.training) %>%
  predict(data.test) %>%
  unname

MSE.standard = 
  data.test %>%
  summarize(MSE = sum( (quality - quality.predict) ^ 2 / n() ) ) %>%
  use_series(MSE)

lambda = 10^seq(7, -2, length = 10)

regression.lasso = cv.glmnet(data.training %>% 
                               select(., -quality) %>% 
                               as.matrix,
                             data.training$quality,
                             alpha = 1,
                             lambda = lambda )

quality.lasso = 
  predict(regression.lasso$glmnet.fit,
          regression.lasso$lambda.min,
          newx = data.test %>%
            select(-quality) %>%
            as.matrix
          )[,1]

MSE.lasso = 
  data.training %>% 
  summarize(MSE = sum( (quality - quality.lasso) ^ 2 / n() ) ) %>%
  use_series(MSE)
```